# RestKit Request Mapping - Post Array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to serialize a **SyncRewardDataRequestModel** in my response body. "**an_id**" serializes fine. However, the **SyncRewardDataInputModel** objects within the NSArray always serializes to a empty NSArray. I have confirmed that I am passing a correct value in my NSArray - Does anyone see what is incorrect with my mapping?

Classes:

```
@interface SyncRewardDataInputModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *test_id;
@end

@interface SyncRewardDataRequestModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *syncRewardDataInputs;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *an_id;
@end
```

The following is my response descriptor:

```
     //Populate mapping
 RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"an_id": @"an_id"}];


RKObjectMapping *syncRewardDataInputsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SyncRewardDataInputModel class]];
[syncRewardDataInputsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"test_id":   @"test_id"}];

//Combine
RKRelationshipMapping *arrayRelation = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"syncRewardDataInputs" toKeyPath:@"downloadCardResponseDTOs" withMapping:syncRewardDataInputsMapping];

[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:arrayRelation];

//Put it in a request
 RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[SyncRewardDataRequestModel class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

return requestDescriptor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
RKObjectMapping *syncRewardDataInputsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SyncRewardDataInputModel class]];
```

should be:

```
RKObjectMapping *syncRewardDataInputsMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
```

because for a request you are always trying to map to an `NSMutableDictionary` so that JSON can be generated from it for transmission.

Often you will have a mapping used for the received data, linked to a response descriptor, and you can use `inverseMapping` on that to generate the mapping to be used for your request descriptor.

Comment: So I can make all my Mappings response mapping and then call inverse mapping if I want to use them as a request mapping?

Comment: Not everything can be reversed, but generally yes (standard nested mappings work well)